# Looking for: A popup implementation in a Java library, with specific actions

Tags: java, filemaker, popupmenu

Filemaker (and, I am given to understand, Amigas) have a popup menu which is different to the JPopup, or the SWT.POPUP in this wise:

It appears when you mousedown over the (say) textfield that holds the currently-selected value.

The selection highlight moves with the mouse pointer as it is dragged.

When you exit (by mouse up) the selection is set to be the item the mouse is over.

If the mouse is not over an item (ie you have exited the menu still dragging) the selected value remains unchanged.

It makes selection from a limited set of options very quick and easy.

Does anyone know of a java implementation that functions this way?

EDIT:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782365/swt-popup-menu-rant-some-code?rq=1

Contains a pretty good implementation of the idea, and I'm happy to take it and work it into my solution.

Comment: Thanks.  I did not know how to do this.  And also, since I last checked, there have been more answers added, some of them useful beyond those I previously saw.  Next project: work out how to inactivate a question once it's relevance slips.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782365/swt-popup-menu-rant-some-code?rq=1

Contains a pretty good implementation of the idea, and I'm happy to take it and work it into my solution.